# Python to build a grid and populating each cell of the grid

Tags: python

Hope someone can assist here, just starting out in Python and would like to know if I'm on the right track for the below.

I have defined a class of objects called Cell...

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.location=(col, row)
        self.value=string
```

There will be a grid of these Cells, I want to work through each Cell in the grid and assign a random value in range 1 to 18 to the self.value of each Cell. I'm thinking to use (col, row) for the X and Y axis of my grid, so each Cell has a (col, row) list.

So, a Grid should be made of populated Cells, is defining the process to build a Grid correct here? (I know 'ask user for size' is not correct, just entered it to note where 'size' comes from)

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, name, col, row, value):
        #ask user for size
        for row in range(size):
            for col in range(size):
                Cell(value) = random.randint(1,18)
```

Comment: What's your specific question? Have you tested the code?

Comment: Your `Cell` class is in last line `self.value=string` probably wrong - the `string` is not known at that place probably.

Comment: `Cell(value) = random.randint(1,18)` doesn't seem to do anything useful.  Is this incomplete?  What are the expected results?

Comment: Jan... yes you're right, I think it should be self.value = value, and assign that value later when it's known (each iteration of the grid-building loop) if that makes sense...

Comment: Brian, that's the bit I'm getting at, I want to say for each Cell, the self.value, should be set to a random number between 1 and 18. I think I am trying to address this value incorrectly.

Comment: Time taken and assistance provided appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few ways to set this up, but it's very dependent on what you require of your output. Do you need to modify cells, move them, add contents to each cell, etc, are all questions you will have to ask before you start designing this.

Here's an example where each cell has a unique name made from its column and grid numbers. Maybe, if each one needs a random attribute as a `value`, you could assign that in the constructor of each cell, then make another list in the `Grid` class that is populated with those values? It really depends on your requirements and how you choose to access these attributes.

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, col_amount, row_amount):

        self.cell_list = [] # empty list to hold all cells

        for col in range(col_amount):
            for row in range(row_amount):
                # create each cell as instance of Cell,
                # with the concatenated col and row numbers
                # as the name, then add the cell.name to cell_list
                cell = Cell(str(col) + '_' + str(row))
                self.cell_list.append(cell.name)


grid = Grid(10,10) # make an instance of Grid with size 10x10
print grid.cell_list
```